# Multiple JMS consumer cosuming same message from Oracle AQ

Tags: oracle, jms

I have an Oracle AQ (definition below)

```
BEGIN
        dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table(queue_table => 'MY_QUEUE',multiple_consumers => FALSE,queue_payload_type => 'MY_OBJECT');
        dbms_aqadm.create_queue(queue_name  => 'MY_QUEUE',queue_table => 'MY_QUEUE');
        dbms_aqadm.start_queue(queue_name => 'MY_QUEUE');
END;
```

Also, I have two different Java processes listening to this queue. I observed sometime same message get consumed by both the Java process despite my queue is created with `multiple_consumers=false` property.  Also my JMS consumers in each process are working in `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode.

Is there any bug in oracle AQ ? or am I missing something?